# iOS7 ignoring retina css media queries - background-size

Tags: iphone, ios, css, media-queries, ios7

Apple have just released their new iOS7 operating system but it's causing issues with my retina icon media queries. It appears the background-size property is being ignored. An example image is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/adZ7X.jpg

The image replacement works perfectly on iPhones 4, 4s, 5 running iOS6 and below (any browser). iOS7 browsers appear to grab the high-res image but ignore the background-size property:

```
@media (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
.b .logo{
  background: url(../img/2x/m-yellloh-logo@2x.png) no-repeat 0 0 !important;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

**What it does do;**

- Replaces the original image with the @2x image

**What it doesn't do;**

- Fit the background image to the div element size.

Tested on iOS7 Safari & Chrome.

Has anyone had this problem, and if so how did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it! Turns out, **iOS7 resets the background-size property** when running a media query. The trick is to specify the background-size with the exact pixel dimensions, or with a 100% value like so;

```
@media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
    only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), 
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
    only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx){
        .logo{
          background: url(../img/2x/logo@2x.png) no-repeat 0 0 !important;
          background-size: 100% !important;
          width: 30px;
          height: 40px;
        }
```

N.b - I also found that including the **!important** tag ensured all retina devices read the query properly, including Samsung S3 & S4. Enjoy.

Answer (score 7):

This is not buggy behaviour. This is your fault.
You set all background properties here:

```
background: url(../img/2x/m-yellloh-logo@2x.png) no-repeat 0 0 !important;
```

so browser treats this as

```
background-image:url(../img/2x/m-yellloh-logo@2x.png) !important 
background-position:0 0 !important 
background-repeat:no-repeat !important 
background-size:auto auto !important 
and so on
```

thus your last line `background-size: 100%;` is overridden by `background-size:auto auto !important;`

Comment: You're completely right. There were many CSS conflicts going on, but I hope this might help others troubleshoot similar ignorance ;)

Comment: This was not the complete solution for me but thanks a lot because it helped me to solve my issue !

Writting the general "background:;" property didn't work at all but as soon as I wrote each one like "background-image", "background-position", "background-size" it worked !!

Answer (score 2):

Because the example is an image. I cannot inspect the code.

You might try the following option:

1. If the div's width and height is fixed. You can set a fixed width and height to the image. also normally the retina-display need the "min-device-pixel-ratio" for high resolution display.

e.g.

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
       and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
.b .logo{
  background: url(../img/2x/m-yellloh-logo@2x.png) no-repeat 0 0 !important;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

or if the div is not fixed.

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
       and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
.b .logo{
  background: url(../img/2x/m-yellloh-logo@2x.png) no-repeat 0 0 !important;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Try if this can fix your issue.

Cheers!

Comment: Your media query including 'min-deivce-pixel-ratio' didn't work, however I fixed it putting a comma between the two queries. It still isn't recognising the background-size property on both scenarios. I'll keep trying to fix this and let you know how I go

Comment: If the background-size is fixed, you can set background-size as fixed width, e.g. 'background-size: 200px'